# How can I set AWS schedule expression to self trigger only once at specific time,date,month,year without repeating?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can I set AWS schedule expression to self trigger cloud event only once at specific time,date,month,year without repeating?

Eg: self trigger cloud event at 7.30am on 2018-10-12 only once and never run again

I tried this format "Cron expression: 30 7 12 10 ? 2018" but it did not self trigger, Any idea on AWS schedule expression format to achieve this requirement?

Thanks In Advance,
Sundar

Answer (score 0):

The expression you tried would set trigger for 7:30 on 2018-10-12 in `UTC Timezone`. Make sure you convert your time to corresponding UTC Timezone from your local timezone before setting the expression.

Answer (score 0):

The format for a specific date/time is:

```
cron(min, hour, day-of-month, month, day-of-week, year)
```

So your format of:

```
cron(30 7 12 10 ? 2018)
```

is correct and would have fired at 07:30 on October 12th in 2018 in UTC - However, as Apoov Agarwal mentioned it would be in UTC.

Unfortunately there are limitations on AWS EventBridge as well; you can only have 200 event "rules" where you create the cron expressions.  But there are other services available which provide more scale:  https://anticipated.io is an example.